# Order of evaluation javascript

Tags: javascript

I am tasked to write a function f in javascript, and

```
f(0)+f(1)//should return 0 if evaluated from left to right
         //should return 1 if evaluated from right to left
```

How can I implement the function f? I am thinking about keeping track of whether f is called before, but have no idea how.

The scheme solution is as following:

(define f
  (let ((set #f))
    (define (fn n)
      (if set
          0
          (begin (set! set #t)
                 n)))
  fn))

Comment: Use a variable somewhere outside the function.

Comment: `f(0)` will be ran before `f(1)` always.  It will never be evaluated "right to left".

Comment: I am not allowed to declare variable outside the function I suppose. It is originally a scheme exercise SICP Ex 3.8, and in the solution there is no variable declared outside f. However, I do not understand scheme so I cannot mimic and translate the solution...

Comment: What would you expect the result to be for `f(0)+f(1)+f(2)` when evaluated from left to right?

Comment: @user122049 If you have a solution, even if in Scheme, please post it.

Comment: `function f(x) { f = function() { return x }; return 0 }` is just one of the many possibilities. But no, you cannot do with pure functions (without external state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scheme solution seems to come down to

```
var f = (function() {
    var set = false;
    function fn(n) {
        if (set) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            set = true;
            return n;
        }
    }
    return fn;
}());
```

which is a bit boring but expected. Yes, you need to keep track of the state somewhere outside of `f`, declaring an extra variable is the simplest solution. It doesn't need to be global though, `set` is hidden in the scope of the IIFE.

Comment: @user122049 You have to redefine `f` after invoking it twice. `set` only works for two calls.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with a property of the function.

```js
function f(v) {
    return [f.value || 0, f.value = v][0];
}

console.log(f(0) + f(1)); // 0
```

```js
function f(v) {
    return [f.value || 0, f.value = v][0];
}

console.log(f(1) + f(0)); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a shorter version...

```
function f(arg) {
    if (!f.called && arg === 0) {
        f.called = true;
        return 0;
    } else if (f.called && arg === 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but cannot declare anything outside function f.

Comment: @user122049 But your question doesn't say that? Anyway, I just added it for clarity to help you understand. There's no need for anything outside the function - see edited version.